# app:mergeTestReleaseResourcesAAPT err(Facade for 495460572) :

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

error environment:jenkins(Only one) 
environment:Windows 
gradle version:4.1 
android studio:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
}
```

When I go through `jenkins` to `gradle assembleTestRelease`,And then we have the following error

> :app:mergeTestReleaseResourcesAAPT err(Facade for 495460572) : No Delegate set : lost message:\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\c97a18b3f1e04b529870aaf58d9b0677\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
>
> AAPT err(Facade for 495460572) : No Delegate set : lost message:\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\c97a18b3f1e04b529870aaf58d9b0677\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
>
> AAPT err(Facade for 495460572) : No Delegate set : lost message:\?\C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\c97a18b3f1e04b529870aaf58d9b0677\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file

How do you solve this problem?

[error.text](https://github.com/LonelyMushroom/GroceriesRoom/blob/master/error.text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the environment variable GRADLE_USER_HOME in jenkins to another folder like c:/Users/someuser